# Zookeeper recursive watch performance

Tags: performance, apache-zookeeper

In Zookeeper 3.6.0 recursive watch was introduced. Related JIRA - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1416

For my application we have about 15_000 nodes and they all need to update some and listen to some attribute changes.

For simplicity, assume there is an abstract concept like Person.

Node_1 can update Person_1 , and all OR few nodes need to get latest data.
Similarly Node_15000 can update Person X, Y, Z and all nodes including self should get latest data.

The Person to Node assignment is not fixed and can change.

Ideally, a Kafka based pub-sub could be used here, but our production requires us to use Zookeeper. Hence in Zookeeper world, what might be right way to have all nodes get updates to each other, or some intelligent way to have nodes only listen to Person they care about (again node to person assignments can change) ?

Is recursive watch scalable for this workload?